# What curve is this?

Tags: geometry, surfaces

This is my earring (see the image please) and my question is: Does this curve have a name? If it does, which one?

[image]
Regards! And thank you.

Comment: It might help if there actually were an image.

Comment: I don't see an image.

Comment: Now there's an image :)

Comment: It's hard to tell from the image, is is one long strand of wire, or interlocking individual rings of wire?

Comment: Could you show this from different angles?

Comment: You might be interested in this: [Wikipedia :: Hopf fibration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopf_fibration)

Comment: It's one long strand of wire... Hopf fobration, let's see.

Comment: In that case, isn't it just some kind of [torus knot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torus_knot)?

Comment: My first guess was that it was a collection of fibers (the circles) of the Hopf fiber bundle $S^3 \to S^2$, which presents the $3$-sphere as collection of circles, parametrized by the $2$-sphere.  This animation by Niles Johnson attempts to help you visualize this.  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AKotMPGFJYk

Comment: @kahen, or a bunch of Villarceau circles...

Comment: I disagree with the close votes.  This has raised a fair amount of interest and 6 upvotes, so how can it be too localized?

Answer (score 3):

Your earring is an example of fibers in the [Hopf fibration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopf_fibration). 
Watch [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AKotMPGFJYk).
Also check [this](https://www.google.com.mx/search?q=hopf+fibration&client=firefox-a&sa=X&rls=org.mozilla%3aes-MX%3aofficial&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&ei=eMFtUYOGJqSi2AWXr4DgBA&ved=0CDgQsAQ&biw=1252&bih=609).

A video of Niles talking about the [Hopf fibration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopf_fibration) can be found [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QXDQsmL-8Us).

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how you want to describe it.  One way is to project it onto a plane and see it as $26$ circles, each of which passes through the origin.  Let $r$ be the radius.  Each one has the form $x^2-2xx_c+y^2-2yy_c=0$ with $(x_c,y_c)$ the center of the circle and $x_c^2+y_c^2=r^2$. If the circles are equally spaced and pass through the origin, we have $(x_c,y_c)_n=(r \cos \frac {n\pi }{13},r \sin \frac {n\pi }{13})$ for $n$ ranging from $0$ through $25$.

Another view would be as a single curve that travels rapidly around the circle while the circle rotates more slowly around the origin.  I would do this as the center of the circle is at $(r \cos \pi t, r \sin \pi t)$ and relative to that the point on the circle is at $(r \cos (26 \pi t - \pi), r \sin (26 \pi t - \pi))$ where the $-\pi $ represents that we start out at the origin.  The total is then $(r \cos \pi t+r \cos (26 \pi t - \pi), r \sin \pi t+r \sin (26 \pi t - \pi))$

Here is a plot from [Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20%28cos%28pi%20t%29%2bcos%2826%20pi%20t%20-%20pi%29,sin%28pi%20t%29%2bsin%2826%20pi%20t%20-%20pi%29%29)

[image: 2D earring]

This is still in two dimensions.  If you want to try to capture the $z$ variation, that is probably also sinusoidal.  Maybe it is over the range $\pm \frac r6$.  In that case it would be $(r \cos \pi t+r \cos (26 \pi t - \pi), r \sin \pi t+r \sin (26 \pi t - \pi),
\frac r6 \sin (26 \pi t))$ but I couldn't get a nice 3D plot out of Alpha.  Maybe somebody with Mathematica can do so.

Comment: Trying to follow the strand on the picture, it looks like one long wire that does as you say, but the plane of the circle is tilted away from the plane. Intriguing.

Comment: @vonbrand:  that is what I was trying to get at with the last part about 3D.

Answer (score 0):

@Ross; I don't think the picture you have is thesame as that in the question. This is clear by mere looking at it. The circles don't pass through any origin and in particular, they don't intersect. Each circle is a fiber over a point on $S^2$.

This is a picture from Hopf fibration. In fact, it is a torus which is a fiber over the circle  by the map $f$ : $S^3$ $\rightarrow$ $S^2$. Any two of the circles you see in the picture are Hopf linked . It is amazing the the circles are not just topological circles but geometric circles.

For more details, watch Niles talk on [link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QXDQsmL-8Us). If you enjoyed that and wants to see more, take a look at [modular fibration](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eqeqbjec97w).